# jQuery form-validation addmethod in multiple forms

Tags: jquery, validation

Short description: Page with ~30 forms, using a custom method to validate with jQuery validation plugin (compares field 1 to field 2 and makes sure field 2 >= field 1).

I basically have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/avmCX/) problem, except there's 30 forms per page and not just 2. I thought I could use the class tag in order for the validation plugin to grab the input that's in the same form that it's validating - but it always goes for the one that's in the first form, even when validating the second form.

Is there a way to make this work without making a separate validation script for every form?

The jsfiddle html code below:

```
<form id='test'>Start :
    <select name='start' class='dayStart'>
        <option value='1'>1</option>
        <option value='1.5'>1.5</option>
        <option value='2'>2</option>
    </select>
    <br />Stop :
    <select name='stop' class='dayStop'>
        <option value='1'>1</option>
        <option value='1.5'>1.5</option>
        <option value='2'>2</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <input type='submit' />
</form>
<form id='test2'>Start :
    <select name='start' class='dayStart'>
        <option value='1'>1</option>
        <option value='1.5'>1.5</option>
        <option value='2'>2</option>
    </select>
    <br />Stop :
    <select name='stop' class='dayStop'>
        <option value='1'>1</option>
        <option value='1.5'>1.5</option>
        <option value='2'>2</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <input type='submit' />
</form>
```

And the js here:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("stop_boet_start", function () {
    return (parseFloat($(".dayStop").val()) >= parseFloat($(".dayStart").val()));
}, "* error_msg");

$("#test").validate({
    rules: {
        stop: {
            stop_boet_start: true
        }
    }
});

$("#test2").validate({
    rules: {
        stop: {
            stop_boet_start: true
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find the correct dayStart and dayStop elements you can use following:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("stop_boet_start", function (value, element, params) {
    var form = $(element).closest("form");

    var dayStop = form.find(".dayStop");
    var dayStart = form.find(".dayStart");

    return (parseFloat(dayStop.val()) >= parseFloat(dayStart.val()));
}, "* error_msg");

$("#test").validate({
    rules: {
        stop: {
            stop_boet_start: true
        }
    }
});

$("#test2").validate({
    rules: {
        stop: {
            stop_boet_start: true
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `stop` fields have a common class you can use [addClassRule()](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addClassRules/) add a rule to all those elements.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("stop_boet_start", function () {
        return (parseFloat($(".dayStop").val()) >= parseFloat($(".dayStart").val()));
    }, "* error_msg");

    jQuery.validator.addClassRules("dayStop", {
        stop_boet_start: true
    });

    $("form").validate({});

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Eahtk/)

Or iterate through the list of forms add add the rules like

```
$(".test").each(function () {
    $(this).validate({
        rules: {
            stop: {
                stop_boet_start: true
            }
        }
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Eahtk/5/)

Comment: The problem is, that `$(".dayStop").val()` and `$(".dayStart").val()` will always use the value of the first element with class .dayStop and .dayStart, respectively.

Comment: @chearius yes... need to target the `dayStart` from the same form