# jQuery multiple form validation in 1 page with add method

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-select2

The page contain multiple forms, each of them already has validation implemented with no issue. Due to some circumstances I had to use addMethod for jquery validation in order to make the select2.js work as I want it to. If the value of select is 0, then It shall return false for the validation. The addMethod work for 1 form, when I add in addMethod of other form, the validation seems not working properly anymore.

[demo site click here](http://greysaga.com/demo/report/)

**Scenario**
click on the "report" button to top left > click Conversion Rate report button then one of the form will show, click on the "search" button, then the error message will show. By default the error message will gone respectively when the input field has value in it. As for the select2 dropdown, the error message still remain (weird) even there is value in it instead of just "Select country". As of now the error message will still persist even if you open up another form. Now click on "country report" button, another form will show up, click on the search button, error message will show up because the input field is empty, now select a country from the select2 dropdown. The error message gone (good). While you at this, go back to conversion rate report form, then you will see the select2 error message is gone. even If I change the selection in it, it won't trigger the error message anymore.

I know its a lot to read, but please help your fellow "intermediate" front-end developer, thanks!

**HTML element**

```
<form id="search_country_report_form" action="con_sum.html">
            <span class="close_search_pop lnr lnr-cross"></span>
            <div class="report_search block_padding">
                <h2>Search Country report</h2>

                <ul class="report_search_date_range clearfix">
                    <li><span><b>Date range*</b></span></li>
                    <li>
                        <label>From</label><input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="startStringDate" id="search_country_date_from" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>to</label><input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="endStringDate" id="search_country_date_to" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="report_search_top_cat clearfix">
                    <li>
                        <label><b>Country name*</b></label>
                        <select id="search_country_country_name" name="countryName">
                            <option value="0">Select country</option>
                            <option value="TH">Country #1</option>
                            <option value="MY">Country #2</option>
                        </select>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="btn_wrap clearfix">
                    <button class="search_btn" type="submit">Search</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

**jQuery script**

```
$("form").each(function () {
        var search_country_report = $('#search_country_report_form');

        $.validator.addMethod("countryNameCheck", function (value) {
            var theField = $("#search_country_country_name");
            if (theField.val() === '0') {
                console.log($("#search_country_country_name").val());
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
                console.log($("#search_country_country_name").val());
            }
        });

        var validobj = search_country_report.validate({
            rules: {
                startStringDate: {
                    required: true
                },
                endStringDate: {
                    required: true
                },
                countryName: {
                    required: true,
                    countryNameCheck: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                startStringDate: "Required",
                endStringDate: "Required",
                countryName: "Country name is required"
            },
            onKeyUp: true,
            errorElement: 'span',
            errorClass: "searchErrorText",
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                var elem = $(element);
                error.insertAfter(element);
            },

            highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                var elem = $(element);
                if (elem.hasClass("select2-offscreen")) {
                    $("#s2id_" + elem.attr("id") + " span").addClass(errorClass);
                } else {
                    elem.addClass(errorClass);
                }
            },

            unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                var elem = $(element);
                if (elem.hasClass("select2-offscreen")) {
                    $("#s2id_" + elem.attr("id") + " span").removeClass(errorClass);

                } else {
                    elem.removeClass(errorClass);
                }
            }
        });

        var thisParent = $('.select2-selection').parent();
        $(document).on("change", thisParent, function () {
            if (!$.isEmptyObject(validobj.submitted)) {
                validobj.form();
            }
        });

        $(document).on("select2-opening", function (arg) {
            var elem = $(arg.target);
            if ($("#s2id_" + elem.attr("id") + " span").hasClass("myErrorClass")) {

                $(".select2-drop span").addClass("myErrorClass");
            } else {
                $(".select2-drop span").removeClass("myErrorClass");
            }
        });

        search_country_report.submit(function () {
            validobj.form();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not `onKeyUp`.   It's `onkeyup` and you can not set it to `true` without breaking something.  Refer to the docs.

[jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onkeyup](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onkeyup)

Secondly, your custom method only needs to be defined once.  Remove it from within your `.each()`.   Actually, the `.validate()` method appears to be the only thing you need inside the `.each()`.

There are likely remaining issues in your code I have not seen.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot guys, with Sparky's help and combine with Chearius [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22527606/jquery-form-validation-addmethod-in-multiple-forms), I move the add method outside of `.each` and got it solved! Just want to share it if someone encounter this problem in future.

```
    $.validator.addMethod("name", function (value, element) {
        // get closest form
        var thisForm = $(element).closest("form");
        // find the target
        var theField = thisForm.find(".select2-hidden-accessible");
        if (theField.val() === '0') {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
```